# Helmet cover starts peeling off: ok or not?

Tags: safety, helmets

Today I noticed that in the back of my helmet the plastic cover of the EPS is starting to detach/peel off from the underlying layer (see photo)

[image]

[image]

I know that attempting to glue it back is a no no as it could affect the behavior of the helmet, however I wonder if it also means it is time to replace the helmet, which I bought 5 years ago.

Comment: Can't quite tell where on the helmet this is - it is clearly a sharp corner exposed and takes damage from being handled ?

Comment: Can we have a larger picture showing where on the helmet this is. I suspect its located in in a place that affects a cosmetics or aerodynamics, not safety.

Comment: @Criggie added, hope it's more clear

Comment: Helmets can be contentious and spiral away from the root - so please try and focus on the question.

Comment: Glue will not damage the helmet's effectiveness. Glue was the only thing that used to hold this plastic shell together with the EPS body.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't replace my helmet unless the area peeling is actually much bigger than the photo suggests.  The chances of crashing AND hitting your head at the angle required to rip the shell off AND hitting your head again with sufficient force to be a problem seem fairly minimal.

**However**, a quick google shows most manufacturers recommend replacing your helmet every 3-5 years so as yours is 5 years old that may be a good reason to change.

Comment: Refer https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/83787/bike-helmet-expiration/83788#83788 regarding the debate of helmet age and scientific evidence helmets that have no visible damage do not need to be replaced.

Comment: I know its opinion, but 5 years seems a bit short - all my helmets have lasted 9-11 years excluding the one that did its job.

Comment: I agree, and I tend to keep my helmets more like 7-8 years by which point the padding has pretty much disintegrated.  But then i'm also not a helmet manufacturer and I assume despite my choices they know more than i do

Comment: ...Also, you're not in risk of getting sued in case some lawyer finds out that it's _theoretically possible_ their client's head injury could have been reduced by replacing the helmet, and your company may have not have clearly enough pointed to that possibility. Nor do you have a vested interest in people replacing their helmets regularly...

Answer (score 8):

For something like that I'd just put some plastic tape like sellotape or white electrical insulation tape to minimise the plastic peeling off.  I would not use glue, because finding a glue that is safe for the foam AND for the shell might be difficult.

I have seen helmets where the outer plastic coating is significantly or completely missing - those absolutely require replacement because the outer layer stops the polystychrene foam from digging into the road in an event where the helmet meets the road.

For some minor peeling like this, just stop it getting worse and you're good for the life of the helmet.

You have done really well to notice and resolve the issue before it gets bad.

Answer (score 2):

That cover plastic is not structural, it will not absorb impact forces, but has an important job. The only reason it might be dangerous is if you crash at very high speed, and the entire smooth plastic suddenly rips away from the surface of the helmet. In this case, the soft non-smooth expanded polystyrene will touch the rough road directly at high speed. The impact causes deformations, which could lead to a massive rotational force to your head because the helmet won't then slide over the road but want to stay in place, leading to rotation of your head.

There are mechanisms in modern helmets that are designed to reduce rotational forces, called MIPS. If your helmet doesn't have MIPS, you alone for that reason should change it to one that has MIPS, and at the same time ensure your new helmet is also Snell certified (most are certified only to weaker standards and not Snell) and is made using in-mold technology where a rigid polycarbonate frame is molded inside the expanded polystyrene, to increase its structural strength.

I am of the opinion that helmets do not do much in a hard crash, because the standards are so ridiculously weak and the only way to make cyclists actually wear helmets is to make them so full of holes that you are mostly wearing holes over your head.

However, there is one mechanism, rotational forces, which could make a helmet *even more dangerous* than not wearing a helmet. Please make sure to ensure this doesn't happen by only using MIPS helmets and ensuring your helmet has a smooth outer layer, if it's a separate plastic layer then that separate plastic layer needs to stay on the helmet during a crash and not detach in a crash.

If the peeling is limited to the end, and you can't easily peel the entire cover away, the it isn't an issue. If the peeling easily extends to the whole cover, then it is an issue.

Comment: *I am of the opinion that helmets do not do much in a hard crash*  I've hit pavement head-first at 40+ mph/60+ kph.  The fact that I can even reply to that is clear evidence that it's not always true.  *However, there is one mechanism, rotational forces, which could make a helmet even more dangerous than not wearing a helmet.*  That may very well be true - the hard plastic surface of my helmet had significant scoring as if it was dragged hard across the pavement.  That hard surface likely is why I'm still alive.

Comment: (cont) I suspect though, that even soft polystyrene foam slides across pavement better than flesh and bone do, even if not as well as a harder/smoother cover.

Comment: Good read for anyone wanting to know more about MIPS and claims MIPS makes helmets safer (Spoiler alert - no one is prepared to claim it does) . https://www.pelotonmagazine.com/gear/mips-the-reality-behind-making-helmets-safer/

Comment: *"so full of holes that you are mostly wearing holes over your head"* This is ridiculous nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key question here is "**why** did the hard plastic start separating?"

I suspect that the OP, like many of us, rides in the daytime with the helmet exposed to UV light from the sun.  UV light, having relatively high energy, can break chemical bonds in the plastic, weakening it over time. How much weakening happens and how quickly varies with plastic composition and UV exposure, but it seems plausible to me that the OP's peeling plastic is a symptom of underlying degradation of the plastic and so the helmet should be replaced post-haste.

Comment: Given its right on an exposed corner, I'd suspect that general handling is more of an issue than being in sunlight.  I ride in the southern hemisphere where the ozone layer is thinner.    In the height of summer I can acquire a sunburn riding after 6 PM, and my helmet does not appear to weaken over a decade of riding.