# Prescription Sunglasses for Cyclists

Tags: glasses

I'd like to get some quality prescription sunglasses for cycling. Can anyone make some suggestions on a brand they like?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Your question may be a duplicate.

Comment: This [one](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7127/prescription-eye-glasses-and-shoulder-checks) and [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1666/what-are-the-features-that-i-should-seek-in-cycling-glasses). Personally, I am using Rudy Project currently, but have also used Bolle and Oakley. Also, my preference is to wear contacts and not use prescriptive glasses; as it's cheaper to not have to replace the lenses on the eyewear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love my Oakley Fives.

Pros:

- The frames are relatively cheap
- They're very light and comfortable to ride in
- They provide good coverage and keep out dust/grime and breeze
- The arms are designed to detach when under pressure rather than break
- I think they look good

I have transition lenses and they are fantastic. I never have to worry about changing lenses or having the wrong tint. I just chuck them on and go and they're always spot on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that almost every Spy sunglass model can be made into an Rx lens. No insert, which i really like since inserts can be too close to my eyes, or fog too quickly.

i use the [Spy Logan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00295XHCW) which is a full wrap. The breathe well, and fit by large head. They are pretty affordable, and took the prescription well.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wearing Wiley X [Airrage](http://www.wileyx.com/EcommSuite/ProductDetail.aspx?ActivityCode=MOTORCYCLE&SeriesCode=CLIMATE_CONTROL&ProductLine=746,AIRRAG&ItemCode=697) with [Transitions®](http://en-us.transitions.com/en/default.aspx?gclid=CKPWnpLNtLACFbEBQAodLglwTQ) (photo sensitive) lenses for cycling, shooting, offroading in my topless Land-Rover, [Burning Man](http://burningman.com/) (dust storms in the Black Rock Desert) and as general purpose safety glasses when working in the shop. The [Airrage](http://www.wileyx.com/EcommSuite/ProductDetail.aspx?ActivityCode=MOTORCYCLE&SeriesCode=CLIMATE_CONTROL&ProductLine=746,AIRRAG&ItemCode=697) features  removable gaskets (great for dusty conditions and my allergy season), a removable headband. and a  curved "wrap around" frame that fits my face well. Wiley X offers a number of styles to suit individual needs and preferences.

(My avatar happens to be a photo taken at Burning Man after a full day of dust storms. Unfortunately, I didn't have the Wiley X's that year.)

[image: image of Wiley X Airrage]